# jQuery: Scroll in fixed element when page resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a fixed navigation element that starts from 0,0 and is flush to the left and bottom sides of the screen. When the screen is resized vertically to a point where the links in the navigation over flow on the screen, I want to be able to scroll up and down within the navigation element. How would I do this? I have tried searching but all i can find is setting elements to fixed once a page is scrolled.

Comment: can you upload some code or image?

Answer (score 0):

You could put it inside a wrapper and add overflow:auto to the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
        <li>item x</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height:100%;}

.sidebar {position:fixed;left:0;top:0;padding:5%;height:90%;background:#eee;}
.wrapper {height:90%;overflow:auto;padding:5%;width:100px;}

ul {margin:0;padding:0;}
li {margin-bottom:30px;list-style:none;}
```

Fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/36erB/1/